# How to use 2 public classes, protected void on creat functions in the same fragments?

Tags: android-studio, class, void, protected, simultaneous

1. How to put more than one class,overview,void in MainActivity java of Android Studio? I need to have both the button and a code to make the map of google have some restricions in the same page. What names of the classes should be changed for it to work. The codes work when put independently but not together.How to make them work good together?

   ```
        package com.example.maps;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;

        import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


        public class FirstFragment extends AppCompatActivity {
           Button button;
           @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
             button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      openFoodFragment();
                   }
              });
           }
          public void openFoodFragment(){
               Intent intent = new Intent(this, FoodFragment.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
        }
       public class MainACTIVITY extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

           GoogleMap mapAPI;
          SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
          @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              mapFragment =(SupportMapFragment)
                      getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapAPI);

               mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
           }
           public void openFoodFragment(){
              Intent intent = new Intent(this, FoodFragment.class);
              startActivity(intent);
           }
         @Override
          public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
             mapAPI =  googleMap ;

             LatLng one = new LatLng(-21.754812, -48.219451);
             LatLng two = new LatLng(-21.787443, -48.113332);

            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

            //add them to builder
            builder.include(one);
            builder.include(two);

            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

            //get width and height to current display screen
            int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
            int padding = (int) (width * 0.20);
            mapAPI.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(bounds);
             mapAPI.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding));

             //set zoom to level to current so that you won't be able to zoom out viz. move outside       bounds
            mapAPI.setMinZoomPreference(mapAPI.getCameraPosition().zoom);


            LatLng Kampai = new LatLng(-21.780985, -48.186859);
            mapAPI.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Kampai).title("Kampai"));
            mapAPI.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Kampai));

            }

            }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the can be in the same file but you have your mainACTIVITY inside your FirstFragment which cannot happen you need to remove the bottom most bracket and place it right above the start of your mainACTIVITY class, your FirstFragment's brackets need to close before you paste another class into the file.

Comment: this happens when i do that:    error: duplicate class: com.example.maps.FirstFragment
public class FirstFragment extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

Comment: then it's not possible to have an activity and a fragment in the same java file, you can have classes but not ones with oncreate and stuff